# Using Jquery to slowly hide a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I'm trying to make some code which finds if a div exists, and if it does then have it fade away slowly. I have this to determine whether or not the div exists

```
    if($('#error').length != 0)
 {
  $('#error').hide(500);
 }
```

And that does work but only on a refresh, I've been attempting to put it in a timer like this:

```
   var refreshId = setInterval(function()
   {
      if($('#error').length != 0)
 {
  $('#error').hide(500);
 }   
   }, 500);
```

But its not getting rid of the innerHTML! I have some code which on hover alters the innerHTML of the error div so I can fill it up, but for some reason this isn't working, any advice would help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("#error").fadeOut(500);
```

Update:

If you are looking to check for existence:

```
var msg = $("#error");
if(msg.length) {
  msg.fadeOut(500);
}
```

If you want to empty it:

```
$("#error").empty();
```

Comment: Oh, I agree.  However, in his statement he is checking for existence which may or may not be used elsewhere in his program for other reasons.  Thought I might as well add it, in general I recommend just using the first line.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to delay 500ms then fade out, do this:

```
$("#error").delay(500).fadeOut();
```

To also empty the element, provide a callback to `.fadeOut()` like this:

```
$("#error").delay(500).fadeOut(function() {
  $(this).html('');
});
```

There's no need to check `.length`, if an element that matches the selector isn't present, nothing happens :)

Answer (score 0):

The div you're trying to hide likely hasn't loaded by the time your script runs. Try this; it will defer execution until the DOM is loaded:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   // put your code here
 });
```

This is a good practice when using jQuery anyway.

Reference: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready()